# Add new value to each object in state array with a condition

Tags: android, react-native

I have a state array called 'deals' that contains data similar to below; I want to make a request to another API and add a value from the response to the deals state array only if it meets a certain condition.

**For example;**

Only add the `header_image` value which I get from the response to an object in the `deals` state array but only if the `deals` state array has a value of `isSteam=true`

**Current**

```
[
 {
      "added":1567049314,
      "drm":[
         "steam"
      ],
      "expiry":1567443600,
      "game_code":"224280",
      "isSteam":true,
      "plain":"rpgmakervxacelite",
      "price_cut":80,
      "price_new":13.99,
      "price_old":69.99,
      "shop":{
         "id":"steam",
         "name":"Steam"
      },
      "title":"RPG Maker VX Ace Lite",
      "urls":{
         "buy":"https://store.steampowered.com/app/224280/",
         "game":"https://isthereanydeal.com/game/rpgmakervxacelite/info/"
      }
   }
 ---More Data---
 }
]
```

**Expected**

```
[
     {
          "added":1567049314,
          "drm":[
             "steam"
          ],
          "expiry":1567443600,
          "game_code":"224280",
          "isSteam":true,
          "game_image": "https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steam/apps/224280/header.jpg?t=1540461421",
          "plain":"rpgmakervxacelite",
          "price_cut":80,
          "price_new":13.99,
          "price_old":69.99,
          "shop":{
             "id":"steam",
             "name":"Steam"
          },
          "title":"RPG Maker VX Ace Lite",
          "urls":{
             "buy":"https://store.steampowered.com/app/224280/",
             "game":"https://isthereanydeal.com/game/rpgmakervxacelite/info/"
          }
       },
      ---More Data---
     }
    ]
```

I have the following function where  I make a request and want to add the result to each object in my state array under a condition e.g. where 'IsSteam=true'

```
getGameImage = () => {
      for (var key in this.state.deals) {
        if (this.state.deals[key]['isSteam']) {
          // Get Images
          axios.get('https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=' + this.state.deals[key]['game_code'])
          .then((response) => {
            var parsedData = JSON.parse(response['request']['_response'])
            for(var key in parsedData) {
              var result = this.state.deals.map(function(el) {
                var o = Object.assign({}, el);
                if(o['isSteam']) {
                  o.game_image = parsedData[key]['data']['header_image'];
                }
                return o;
                })
                this.setState({deals: result});
                console.log(result)
             }
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
          })
          }        
       }
    }
```

Problem is that; it does add the URL of the image to only objects where `IsSteam=true` but it adds the **same** image URL (probably the very first one it gets) to all objects where `isSteam=true`.

I want the correct image URL to display for each game and the link between my current deals array and the response from the API is the game code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

```
getGameImage = async () => {
      for(var key in this.state.deals) {
        let duplicateArray = [...this.state.deals]
        if(this.state.deals[key]['isSteam']) {     
          await this.setGameImage(this.state.deals[key]['game_code'])
          duplicateArray[key].game_image = this.state.imageUrl;
        }
        else {
          duplicateArray[key].game_image = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mYrKAMLbjYA/maxresdefault.jpg';
        }
        this.setState({deals: duplicateArray});
      }
      }
```